# How can I upload different parts of a .txt to different strings

Tags: java, arrays, text, import

So I have this assignment that I'm part way stuck on, I need to start it off by adding information to different arrays about hurricanes from one text document. I understand you should use for loops, but can you give me an example or a good answer please? By the way, in the code below, I keep getting an error of the nextInt going out of bounds of the array (it's not stopping)

Oh and if you could (and if it's possible) could you give the answer using for-each loops?
Thank you so much!

Variables and imports:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{
    //declare and initialize variables


    int arrayLength = 59;
    int [] year = new int[arrayLength];
    String [] month = new String[arrayLength];
    int [] pressure = new int[arrayLength];
    double [] windSpeed = new double[arrayLength];
    String [] hurcName = new String[arrayLength];

    File fileName = new File("/Users/jerome/Desktop/hurcdata.txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);

    //INPUT  - read data in from the file
    int index = 0;
```

And here's my attempt at adding the text file to the arrays:

```
//INPUT  - read data in from the file
    int index = 0;
    while (inFile.hasNext())
    {
        month[index] = inFile.next();
        index++;
    }
    inFile.close();
    while (inFile.hasNext())
    {
        pressure[index] = inFile.nextInt();
        index++;
    }
    inFile.close();
    while (inFile.hasNext())
    {
        windSpeed[index] = inFile.nextInt();
        index++;
    }
    inFile.close();
```

Sample data from `hurcdata.txt`:

```
1980 Aug 945 100 Allen
1983 Aug 962 100 Alicia
1984 Sep 949 100 Diana
1985 Jul 1002 65 Bob
1985 Aug 987 80 Danny
1985 Sep 959 100 Elena
...
```

Comment: I don't think many people here will simply answer your homework assignment but many will be more than willing to point you in the right direction and provide some help. What do the contents of `hurcdata.txt` look like? Also, in your code to read the data, it looks like you're reading all tokens in the file and then closing the file and attempting to read from a closed file in subsequent loops; this might be the cause of your errors when calling `nextInt`.

Comment: Your `index` will be off as well, after the first loop it will be something other than 0 (assuming there were tokens to read), so the next array will begin insertion at an index greater than 0; this could cause out of bounds exceptions.

Comment: this is part of hurcdata.txt

    1980 Aug 945 100 Allen
1983 Aug 962 100 Alicia
1984 Sep 949 100 Diana
1985 Jul 1002 65 Bob
1985 Aug 987 80 Danny
1985 Sep 959 100 Elena
1985 Sep 942 90 Gloria
1985 Oct 971 75 Juan
1985 Nov 967 85 Kate
1986 Jun 990 75 Bonnie
1986 Aug 990 65 Charley
1987 Oct 993 65 Floyd
1988 Sep 984 70 Florence
1989 Aug 986 70 Chantal
1989 Sep 934 120 Hugo
1989 Oct 983 75 Jerry
1991 Aug 962 90 Bob
1992 Aug 922 145 Andrew
1993 Aug 960 100 Emily
1995 Aug 973 85 Erin
1995 Oct 942 100 Opal

Comment: It goes in order but it is weird looking in the comment

Answer (score 0):

`while( inFile.next() )` will read until the file is empty. So every delimiter the Scanner hits is being placed into your `month` array.

Consider what a "set" of data looks like. You will want to read in each set until there is no more data. Some pseudocode:

```
while( inFile.next() )
{
  //read part1 into first array
  //read part2 into second array
  //read part3 into third array
}
inFile.close();
//now arrays are full.
//Do other stuff...
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the data in the file is set to a specific number of records, but to be safe it would be a good idea to have a counter inside your loop to ensure that you're not trying to add data to an array outside of its bounds. ex. `while (inFile.next() && count < arrayLength)`